# Why when I suck water of a tube and connect that tube to a lower tank water keeps flowing towards lower one? (syphon)

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, fluid-dynamics, pressure, flow, bernoulli-equation

[image]

lets say I suck water of a tube then put that tube in a lower tank why does water keeps flowing even when there is a component of gravity up.

my guess is that by bernullis law I add up some speed in the lower part of the tube then there is lower pressure there.then the air will flow towars lower pressure.

Comment: I would like to see some equations

Comment: Are you asking what pulls the liquid up over the rim of the upper vessel before it flows down to the lower vessel? See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Siphon (plenty of equations there.) P.S., Pressure of the liquid at the highest point is less than atmospheric pressure. The siphon only works if the tube is stiff enough that the pressure difference won't collapse it.

Comment: @SolomonSlow I would love to see your full explanation

Comment: It's not about Bernoulli. It's due to a combination of the fact water flows downhill and a vacuum inside the tube being produced inside the tube if an air bubble is formed, which gets around the "uphill" part inside the tube.